# How to fix version problems with TeXLive & tlmgr

Tags: latex, tex, tex-live, tlmgr

I installed TeXLive following the instructions [here](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/161096), and the installer told me that I am installing the 2020 version:

```
Loading http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Installing TeX Live 2020 from: http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
...
```

However, asking `tex --version` returns me:

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

I changed the repository for tlmgr as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429718/161096):

```
sudo tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final
```

But now is gives me errors that 2017 is no longer supported.
Which is the reason that I cannot install packages:

```
~$ tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final (verified)
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available.
```

and

```
~$ tlmgr install nicefrac
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final (verified)
tlmgr install: package nicefrac not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

How do I install the 2020 version of TeX or how can I properly use tlmgr without getting these errors?

Comment: My guess would be that you have multiple texlive versions installed. Can you test if the tlmgr works if you explicitly use the 2020 one, e.g. something like `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64......./tlmgr` (check what the exact path on your system is)